# Expected HashSet<&'a str> but found HashSet<&&str>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn the ropes with Rust, and I was playing around with this little function:

```rust
fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&'a str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    // count_letters returns a HashMap<char, u32> with occurrence count for each letter
    let letter_count = count_letters(word);
    HashSet::from_iter(possible_anagrams.iter().filter(|anagram| {
        // Basically, if both words have the same letter count, they are anagrams
        letter_count.eq(&count_letters(anagram))
    }))
}
```

However, when I attempt to build this I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:15:5
   |
13 |   pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&'a str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
   |                                                                         ---------------- expected `HashSet<&'a str>` because of return type
14 |       let letter_count = count_letters(word);
15 | /     HashSet::from_iter(possible_anagrams.iter().filter(|anagram| {
16 | |         letter_count.eq(&count_letters(anagram))
17 | |     }))
   | |_______^ expected `str`, found `&str`
   |
   = note: expected struct `HashSet<&'a str, RandomState>`
              found struct `HashSet<&&str, _>`
```

Now, I'm quite lost on what's going on here.

From my ignorant perspective, I can deduce that I'm creating an iterator over a slice over borrowed elements, so I can kind-of understand how, after the filtering, we'd end up with an `Iterator<Item=&&str>`, but from my understanding Rust should automatically deref that into `&str` when needed.

So, what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`possible_anagrams.iter()` produces an iterator of `&&str`.

Add [`copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) to iterator to change from iterator of `&&str` to `&str`:

From the docs:

> This is useful when you have an iterator over &T, but you need an iterator over T.

```rust
fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&'a str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    // count_letters returns a HashMap<char, u32> with occurrence count for each letter
    let letter_count = count_letters(word);
    HashSet::from_iter(possible_anagrams.iter().copied().filter(|anagram| {
        // Basically, if both words have the same letter count, they are anagrams
        letter_count.eq(&count_letters(anagram))
    }))
}
```